Solving Circular Reference in Spring Boot with RequiredArgsConstructor
I am trying to create a java spring boot service and I have the following issue. Suppose we have a dating app with a likes and dislikes table. We need to check if the users have interacted in the past and they did we may need to throw an exception. So the classes might have to look like this:
@Service
@RequiredArgsConst
public class LikeService {
    private final DislikeService dislikeService;
    public void method() {
        // check if dislike exists and save
    }
}


@Service
@RequiredArgsConst
public class DislikeService {
    private final LikeService likeService;
    public void method() {
        // check if like exists and save
    }
}

This will definitely result in a circular reference error. A solution that could probably solve this without changing the design would be:
@Service
@RequiredArgsConst
public class LikeService {
    @Lazy
    private final DislikeService dislikeService;
}

However, @lazy annotation is ignored. Is there any way I can use the @RequiredArgsConstructor with the @lazy annotation only on specific fields? I want the generated constructor to look something like this for the like service:
public LikeService(final RandomService randomService, final AnotherService anotherService, @Lazy final DislikeService dislikeService) {
    this.randomService = randomService;
    this.anotherService = anotherService;
    this.dislikeService = dislikeService;
}

Solutions that sound like bad design to me: Using a mediator service. Suppose me have an interaction service that includes the like and dislike service. This will solve the circular reference issue, however the like and dislike methods will be accessible from every other service, skipping any checks we might have set in the interaction service (if they are called directly). So I would want to avoid that.
Recomendations: You are more than welcome to help me out by giving me examples of alternative design patterns except mediator services or by linking guides for good design principles.
Note: I have decided to merge the likes and dislikes table and use an enum to determine the interaction. I am only asking for a solution in case I have to deal with a similar issue in the future and out of pure interest.

That is correct. However how would you solve this issue if you were writing the app? I have explained the issue with using a mediator service. I have started to merge the like and dislike tables in a single interaction table. But if you had to keep both entities separate, Like and Dislike how would you handle the circular reference?


I am looking for a constructor based solution, preferably a generated one

Impossible. You can't have both the service classes have a final field to contain an instance of the other. Think about it. This has nothing to do with lombok's @RequiredArgsConstructor and instead everything to do with how one would construct such a pair. At least one class has to split up its construction and the setting of its sibling.
Java as a language fundamentally does not have a placeholder mechanic. There simply isn't a concept of 'Give me a reference or handle or similar now that I will update later'. You can write it yourself, but now you're just kicking the can down the road: Your 2 service classes have all final fields, but those are of objects that themselves are mutable.
The usual solution in the java ecosystem to have a two-phase instance: In the construction phase, the instance has a handful of mutable aspects to it. At some point the instance is 'locked' at which point all ways to change them no longer work (for example, start throwing exceptions). This isn't compiler enforced, you just.. write methods. In other words, all fields are private and once the field boolean locked; is set to true, all methods in the class that can modify that field will refuse to do so, and no code in the class ever sets locked to false.
If you dislike the lack of symmetry / lack of final, an alternative design involves each service not having access to its sibling at all, or having a class that represents the pair - instances of that class contain fields that refer to each sibling, and any operation that is fundamentally designed to require both is in that class; the siblings just provide (in package private methods probably) whatever low level feature needs to be made available to the class representing the pair so that it can do the job.
You even get away with all-final here and even have the siblings know about their 'container':
class OpinionServicePair {
  final LikeService like;
  final DislikeService dislike;

  OpinionServicePair() {
    this.like = new LikeService(this);
    this.dislike = new DislikeService(this);
  }
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor
class LikeService {
  private final OpinionServicePair owner;

  public DislikeService getDislikeService() {
    return this.owner.dislike;
  }
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor
class DislikeService {
  private final OpinionServicePair owner;

  public LikeService getLikeService() {
    return this.owner.like;
  }
}

However, note that under the hood this is an 'inproper constructor', which leaked its own this during its construction. Various linter tools will flag this and certain esoteric rules about how the java memory model works no longer apply. This probably isn't relevant. Just pointing out - even this solution isn't actually perfectly, no caveats utterly immutable/functional compatible design. Because that's not something that's possible when you need a 2-way linked set of objects.
You may be tempted to add e.g. a field final DislikeService dislike;' to the LikeService class, and a line in the constructor: this.dislike = owner.dislike;, but this would not work - part of the problem with improper construction is that final itself no longer means what you think it means: One of those XLikeService constructors will observe one or both owner.like and owner.dislike being null. Yes, a final field isn't unchanging: It can be null first and have a value later. This cannot happen (or rather, the compiler won't let you access it when it is still null), unless you have an improper constructor situation such as this example.
Now that you know the caveats about doing it this way - judge for yourself if you feel this is a more suitable way to go. If you want to stick with simply the two services and no wrappers, those fields cannot be final (at least, not without resorting to far more damaging hackery than the improper construction issue with the solution offered here).
NB: The above is still circular design; circular design causes problems. But then again, sometimes you need it. Another answer to this question is basically 'your code is stinky and you should just get rid of the circular design'. If that is on the table, you should probably just do that instead. However, don't bend over backwards. It's one of those 'in a perfect world, ....' bits of advice. You often can't just write out the circular requirement. From time to time the architectural 'cure' to remove the circular requirement causes a lot of other style faux passes, thus, trivially, making the cure worse than the disease.

You can use @Autowired instead of @Lazy.
Here is example:
@Service
@RequiredArgsConst
public class LikeService {
    @Autowired
    private DislikeService dislikeService;
}

But proper solution is to redesign your application. Circular dependency is sign of architectural problem.

Field injection is bad design. I am looking for a constructor based solution, preferably a generated one

Circular dependency is bad design. Field injection is just a symptom.

@PiccoloNamek Field injection is bad because it treats a symptom, not the disease. The 'disease', that must be treated is the bad design, which leads to circular dependency.

This looks like a better fix for my issue:
#Service
public class LikeService {
private final DislikeService dislikeService;
#Autowired
public LikeService(#Lazy DislikeService dislikeService) {
     this.dislikeService = dislikeService;
}

}
Using constructor based injection is superior to field injection for many reasons.
However that is not what I asked. I am looking for a lombok generated constructor solution ideally.

@talex You're being rather condescending here. Sure, yes, circular setups like OP has result in various flavours of pain. If you can trivially eliminate the circular setup, of course, that is the right answer. But often it isn't that simple, and even if you think its reasonable to just casually go: You should just toss everything in the garbage and start over - you may well end up with a new design that is on net worse. You solve one style issue (circular refs) and commit 5 far more problematic different ones. I implore you to stop parroting pithy architecture/style maxims like this.

@rzwitserlootI just answered to Field injection is bad design in same style. Nowhere I suggested to scrap everything, just point to the root of problem. So who is condescending here?
